# Filter a range by both Row and Column criteria in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a set of data that I want to filter by both the rows and columns.

I want to create a function like `FILTER(B4:L8, (B2:L2 = "Email")+(B2:L2 = "All"), A4:A8 = "Email")` to filter the data in the image below. However this does not work, how would I go about this?

[image]

Example Google Doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JIGXmOKkb_llfnrfJmdbiwFG97tiL3E3PnDuhy3r9x8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) command documentation says,

> In order to filter both rows and columns, use the return value of one FILTER function as range in another.

Like so:

```
=filter(filter(A4:L8, (A2:L2="Email")+(A2:L2="All")), A4:A8="Email")
```